# how can i create a favorites button for my quotes app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an android app which displays quotes, would like to add "Save Quote As favourite" based on users selection of particular quote.

Once user saves Fav quotes and wants to see those quotes only, app should show those quotes, in a section of the navbar.

the problem is that i called my quotes with an API and how can i introduce the favorite button to Quotes in a API? is that possible? or i shouldn't have used an API, and should have done by coding?

please can ssomeone help me?

Comment: You need one more Api for add quote in favourite for that you can pass parameter of add favourite in boolean or int and  with that pass quote item id because when you will fetch favourite items list you can display favourite checkbox highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the selected quotes in a local database (like ROOM), then you can show such saved quotes in a recyclerView/list/whatever.

I just finished a very similar project, see if it may help:

https://github.com/mariorobertofortunato/QuoteGenerator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).